# Kivy doesn't use angle-sdl2

Tags: python, matplotlib, opengl, kivy

I have an old computer (about 7 years) and it has an old graphics card so I can't run kivy normaly, I must use a virtual enviroment. That's ok, but I tried to use matplotlib in kivy and than it won't run. It says `[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>` even when I specify `os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'angle_sdl2'`

As I said I tried `os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'angle_sdl2'` and it didn't work.

This it the whole code

```py
import kivy
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from kivy import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')

import os
os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'angle_sdl2'

plt.plot([1, 23, 2, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
        return box

MyApp().run()
```

I got this:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\werto\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-05-14_11.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] No framebuffers extension is supported
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'1.1.0'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Microsoft Corporation'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'GDI Generic'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 1, 1
[CRITICAL] [GL          ] Minimum required OpenGL version (2.0) NOT found!

OpenGL version detected: 1.1

Version: b'1.1.0'
Vendor: b'Microsoft Corporation'
Renderer: b'GDI Generic'

Try upgrading your graphics drivers and/or your graphics hardware in case of problems.

The application will leave now.
```

Comment: You must activate (or install) the OpenGL stuff in your virtual machine.

Comment: But I made it a app earlier and it worked. And it still works. Just this app is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The

Import os
os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'angle_sdl2'

Should be placed above all your code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).